# When Animating a transition from two container child UIViews, the UIViews are empty after the third transition, what's going on?

Tags: xcode, swift, uiview

I have a simple transition animation using the flip method, but somehow after the third iteration, the animation then becomes empty. I should note, a lot of tutorials create an invisible UIView programatically, but I created a physical UIView on the storyboard, and placed two physical Container UIViews on top of the empty UIView (with the first one on top).

I then did a simple first to second transition, and it works. But then, I did the same thing the other way around, and it then transitions to an empty subview, and the rest of the transitions onwards are empty. I'm sure it's no because my statement for a reverse transition is wrong, I added print statements on the proper order of transitions, which appear in console. But the Container UIViews are disappearing after two iterations, and I'm so confused since my code is so simple, I don't know what else is going wrong...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var theView: UIView!

var showingBack = false

@IBAction func actionBtn(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {


    if (showingBack) {
        self.theView.addSubview(firstView)
        UIView.transitionFromView(self.firstView, toView: self.secondView, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight, completion: nil)
        showingBack = false
        println("first to second")


    } else {
        self.theView.addSubview(secondView)
        UIView.transitionFromView(self.secondView, toView: self.firstView, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight, completion: nil)
        showingBack = true
        println("second to first")

    }

}

@IBOutlet var secondView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var firstView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.theView.addSubview(firstView)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

EDIT:

So I'm still struggling with the problem. I thought it may have been a labeling problem, so I colored the background, but it seems the entire view may be removed from the superview hierarchy, and never returned... I still don't know how to solve this, but it's so strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working. In your IB create a view hierarchy as illustrated in the image:

[image]

Then change your code to:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var theView: UIView!

    var showingBack = false

    @IBAction func actionBtn(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        if (showingBack) {
            self.addSubview(firstView, intoView: theView)
            UIView.transitionFromView(self.secondView, toView: self.firstView, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight, completion:{void in
                self.secondView.removeFromSuperview()

            })
            showingBack = false
            println("first to second")


        } else {
            self.addSubview(secondView, intoView: theView)
            UIView.transitionFromView(self.firstView, toView: self.secondView, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight, completion:{void in
                self.firstView.removeFromSuperview()

            })
            showingBack = true
            println("second to first")

        }

    }

    @IBOutlet var secondView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var firstView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.addSubview(firstView, intoView: theView)


    }

    func addSubview(viewToAdd:UIView, intoView superview:UIView) {
        viewToAdd.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        superview.addSubview(viewToAdd)
        superview.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: viewToAdd, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: superview, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
        superview.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: viewToAdd, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: superview, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
        superview.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: viewToAdd, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: superview, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
        superview.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: viewToAdd, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: superview, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Just curious though, why did the subview disappear?

Comment: I can't tell you the exact reason why it didn't work, but I am certain that re-adding subviews multiple times without ever removing them will never work well.